# What is the limit of auto_increment (integer) in mysql

Tags: mysql, integer, auto-increment

I have a mysql database in which i am using auto_increment(integer), can you tell me till what integer it can incremented. How we can increase the limit of auto_increment?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The limit of an `auto_increment` column [is the size of the column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html):

> Use a large enough integer data type for the AUTO_INCREMENT column to hold the maximum sequence value you will need. When the column reaches the upper limit of the data type, the next attempt to generate a sequence number fails. For example, if you use TINYINT, the maximum permissible sequence number is 127. For TINYINT UNSIGNED, the maximum is 255.

The [limits of the integer types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html) are:

```
TINYINT            - 127
UNSIGNED TINYINT   - 255
SMALLINT           - 32767
UNSIGNED SMALLINT  - 65535
MEDIUMINT          - 8388607
UNSIGNED MEDIUMINT - 16777215
INT                - 2147483647
UNSIGNED INT       - 4294967295
BIGINT             - 9223372036854775807
UNSIGNED BIGINT    - 18446744073709551615
```

Answer (score 6):

Integer can go as high as 2147483647. If unsigned it can be 4294967295.

[See this chart](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html) for all of the integer values.

Comment: can we increase the limit by using "BIGINT (9223372036854775807)"?

Comment: If you do one billion increments per second, you have enough in a BIGINT for 292 years of updates. If you have a three node galera cluster, that number drops to  a measly 97 years.

Comment: @opentokix just out of curiosity, why are you dividing it for the number of nodes in the cluster? 

Comment: @AldoB When you use a galera mariadb cluster it will increment by the number of nodes. nodeA will get 1 4 nodeB will get 2 5 and nodeB will get 3 6 and so on when you do "inc"